# In need of assistance fixing a command for my Discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a fun bot for my server and I wanted a spam command, to use it you'd need to include a number of how many times it's gonna spam it, then a message. But as it is right now it won't run, nor does it give me any errors.

```js
function repeat(func, times) {
    func();
    --times && repeat(func, times);
}

exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    if (!args[0] || isNaN(args[0]) || !args[2]) return;
    repeat(function(){
        message.channel.send(args.slice(1).join(' ')).catch(console.log)
    }, args[0]);
}
```

I expect that it's going to spam the message as many times as the number.
For example:

> ME: !spam 3 Hi
>   BOT: Hi
>   BOT: Hi
>   BOT: Hi

Comment: I wouldn't recommend working on such a command. What if someone enters `!spam 30 foo`? Yes I've heard that discord.js deals with the rate limits automatically and prevents such spam, but even so I doubt such bot behaviour would sit well with Discord's ToS.

Answer (score 0):

Try a for instead.

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    if (!args[0] || isNaN(args[0]) || !args[2]) return;
    for (let index = 0; index < args[0]; index++) {
        message.channel.send(args.slice(1).join(' ')).catch(console.log)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    const max = parseInt(args.shift()); // takes the first element of args and converts it to a Number
    if (isNaN(max)) return message.channel.send('You need to enter a valid Number'); // check if its really a number
    if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send('You need to enter a text to send'); // check if spam text is there
    // Add a check to make s sure !spam 100 text is not possible.
    for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) { // For - Loop
        message.channel.send(args.join('')).catch(console.log); // Send it
    }
}
```